# When do you use <% -%> instead of <% %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view-templates

I've noticed that in some lines of rails views, this is used:

```
<% # Code... -%>
```

instead of:

```
<% # Code... %>
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 17):

```
    <ul>
    <% @posts.each do |post| -%> 
      <li><%=post.title%></li>
    <% end -%>
    </ul>
```

There will be no new lines in between the `<ul>` and first `<li>` and the last closing `</li>` and `</ul>`. If the - was omitted, there would.

Comment: Yes. <% -%> suppresses new lines. It can be very useful when doing stuff in plain text (like emails) where that matters.

Answer (score 8):

The different options for evaluating code in ERB are as follows (they can be accessed in Textmate using Ctrl-Shift-. ):

- `<% %>`   Just evaluate the contents.
- `<%= %>`  Evaluate the contents and puts the result.
- `<%= -%>` Evaluate the contents and prints the result.
- `<%# %>`  The contents is treated as a comment and not outputted.

Notice the difference between `puts` and `print`. Puts always adds a new line at the end of the string whereas print doesnt.

Basically, the `-%>` says don't output a new line at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this

```
<div>
    <% if @some_var == some_value %>
    <p>Some message</p>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

The code above yields to the HTML below if the @some_var is some_value

```
<div>

    <p>Some message</p>

</div>
```

If you've put - in the closing tag, then the ERB interpreter would remove the new lines for those with code tag including - and result in the following

```
<div>       
    <p>Some message</p>        
</div>
```

This is useful if you need to have a good looking code for HTML. Sometimes you'll find it useful when working sideby side with a designer

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but I think it's worth pointing out that you can also do this:

```
<%- @posts.each do |post| -%>
  <li><%= post.title %></li>
<%- end %>
```

This strips away any whitespace in front.